# Groovy - integration tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, groovy

I write integration tests for my application using Spock and Spring Framework.

I want to save some objects before each test and remove all after each test.

But problem is that the id generated by Hibernate is not removed after each test. And when I create 2 objects before first test Hibernate generate id 1 and 2 and when I run test findById for id 1 and 2, test is success. But next test for id 1 and 2 is not success, because the objects in database have id 3 and 4.

Here is my code:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ControllerSpec extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository

    private EntityDTO dto

    private MyEntity entity1
    private MyEntity entity2

    @Before
    void set() {
        this.entity1 = new MyEntity(1L)
        this.entity2 = new MyEntity(2L)
        this.dto = new EntityDTO()

        repository.save(this.entity1)
        repository.save(this.entity2)
    }

    @After
    void clean() {
        List<MyEntity> all = repository.findAll()
        if (all != null || !all.isEmpty()) {
            for (MyEntity entity : all) {
                repository.delete(entity)
            }
        }
    }

    @Unroll
    'findById test'() {
        when:
           def response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, EntityDTO)
        then:
           response.getStatusCode() == statusCode
        where:
           url              | statusCode
           '/myurl/id/1'    | HttpStatus.OK
           '/myurl/id/2'    | HttpStatus.OK
           '/myurl/id/3'    | HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
```

And my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/id/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<EntityDTO> findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        final EntityDTO dto = service.findById(id);
        if (dto != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<EntityDTO>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<EntityDTO>(dto, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

And when I run this code I get an error:

> Condition not satisfied:
>
> response.getStatusCode() == statusCode |        |               |  | |
>   404             |  200 |                        false <404 Not
>   Found,{Content-Length=[0], Date=[Thu, 15 Jun 2017 16:07:21 GMT]}>

And when I click 'See diference" I see details: Expected:

> groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: name for class:
>   org.springframework.http.HttpStatus   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getAttribute(MetaClassImpl.java:2820) ... at
>   org.spockframework.runtime.JUnitSupervisor.convertToComparisonFailure(JUnitSupervisor.java:135)

Actual is the same like Expected with one difference:
at

> org.spockframework.runtime.JUnitSupervisor.convertToComparisonFailure(JUnitSupervisor.java:134)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hard code the ID in the test could you use the ID assigned when persisted e.g.

```
...
url                       | statusCode
"/myurl/id/${entity1.id}" | HttpStatus.OK
...
```